# Converting multiple columns to factors and releveling with mutate(across)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

```
dat <- data.frame(Comp1Letter = c("A", "B", "D", "F", "U", "A*", "B", "C"),
                   Comp2Letter = c("B", "C", "E", "U", "A", "C", "A*", "E"),
                   Comp3Letter = c("D", "A", "C", "D", "F", "D", "C", "A"))  

GradeLevels <- c("A*", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "U")
```

I have a dataframe that looks something like the above (but with many other columns I don't want to change).

The columns I am interested in changing contains lists of letter grades, but are currently character vectors and not in the right order.

I need to convert each of these columns into factors with the correct order. I've been able to get this to work using the code below:

```
factordat <-
    dat %>%
      mutate(Comp1Letter = factor(Comp1Letter, levels = GradeLevels)) %>%
      mutate(Comp2Letter = factor(Comp2Letter, levels = GradeLevels)) %>%
      mutate(Comp3Letter = factor(Comp3Letter, levels = GradeLevels))
```

However this is super verbose and chews up a lot of space.

Looking at some other questions, I've tried to use a combination of mutate() and across(), as seen below:

```
factordat <-
  dat %>%
    mutate(across(c(Comp1Letter, Comp2Letter, Comp3Letter) , factor(levels = GradeLetters)))
```

However when I do this the vectors remain character vectors.

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong or offer another option?

Comment: The vectors are not character. They are factors. Its just that you have a dataframe, so you can not tell the difference between the two

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `across` as an anonymous function like this:

```r
dat <- data.frame(Comp1Letter = c("A", "B", "D", "F", "U", "A*", "B", "C"),
                   Comp2Letter = c("B", "C", "E", "U", "A", "C", "A*", "E"),
                   Comp3Letter = c("D", "A", "C", "D", "F", "D", "C", "A"))  

GradeLevels <- c("A*", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "U")

dat %>%
  tibble::as_tibble() %>%
    dplyr::mutate(dplyr::across(c(Comp1Letter, Comp2Letter, Comp3Letter) , ~forcats::parse_factor(., levels = GradeLevels)))

# # A tibble: 8 × 3
#   Comp1Letter Comp2Letter Comp3Letter
#   <fct>       <fct>       <fct>      
# 1 A           B           D          
# 2 B           C           A          
# 3 D           E           C          
# 4 F           U           D          
# 5 U           A           F          
# 6 A*          C           D          
# 7 B           A*          C          
# 8 C           E           A
```

You were close, all that was left to be done was make the factor function anonymous. That can be done either with `~` and `.` in `tidyverse` or `function(x)` and `x` in base R.

Comment: When I attempt this, I still dont' get the correct result

```
factordat <-
  dat %>%
    mutate(across(c(Comp1Letter, Comp2Letter, Comp3Letter) , ~factor(.,levels = GradeLetters))) 
```

I still have all of them as strings...

Comment: I don't think you can tell the difference with regular `data.frame`, so I converted to tibble in my edits for you. Or you can go `sapply(factordat, class)` to verify for yourself the columns types.

Comment: This is not working.
If I inspect the tibble it still shows every variable as a character variable.
The same is true if I use str(factordat)

Comment: similarly, sapply(factordat, class) returns "character" for every column

Comment: I edited to include full code. Please run that code exactly as is. Do you not get the `fct` underneath the column? If so, try `parse_factor` instead of `factor`.

Comment: I return a tibble of only character vectors when using your code and when using parse_factor.

Do I need to be calling mutate or across from a specific library? Is it possible they are being called from the wrong library?

Comment: Try `library(tidyverse)` beforehand. `mutate` is from `dplyr`, and `parse_factor` from `forcats`

Comment: @AlanNielsen I guess some package like `plyr` has masked `dplyr`. Try to specify package with `::`, i.e. `%>% dplyr::mutate(dplyr::across(...))`

Comment: I have already loaded tidyverse, but even loading it directly before running the code I still return a tibble of character vectors...

Comment: using dplyr::mutate has fixed this. plyr is currently masking mutate

Thank you!

Comment: Sure! If this solves your question, consider leaving a green checkmark to show others that it is correct.

Comment: Could you re-share the solution using "starts_with" here in the comments? I'd like to use "ends_with" with "Letter" for this in my actual code.

Comment: Sure you can view the edit history by clicking edits. Also, check this out: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_tidy_select.html